# Changing required Java version for Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ini

My friend was having trouble running Eclipse Luna on his Mac running 10.6.8.  Whenever he ran Eclipse, it would display an error about requiring Java 7.  But, he couldn't install Java 7 due to his older OS.

After running through some strategies for solving this issue online, I failed to find a solution.  So, I decided to open up the `eclipse.ini` file and changed this line:

```
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
```

to this:

```
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
```

Then, Eclipse ran.  It didn't run into an error yet.

Is this an issue of Eclipse requiring a more recent Java version than needed, or will it start to run into problems at some point?

Comment: He will start to run in to problems. Parts of Eclipse need Java 7

Comment: @greg-449 Do you know which parts? I ran through many of the basics and couldn't find anything broken

Comment: No I don't, but the Eclipse developers don't change the requirements without good reason.

Comment: You don't mention what release of Eclipse. A solution might be to downgrade to 3.x or something which may only need Java 6. This implies you can't easily develop for Java 7 or beyond with this setup (as the VM you target for a project needs to run locally).

Comment: Why can't your friend install Java 7? Can't you just use an older version of eclipse?

Comment: @KevinWorkman Apparently for Mac's they need a newer version of the OS in order to install Java 7. An older version could potentially work, but I'm curious why this solution seems to work.

Comment: Just as a followup, he's used it the entire semester and ran into no issues

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The decision to require Java 1.7 is described in great detail in Eclipse bug [423734](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=423734)

The primary reason initially was that Java 1.6 is now end of life and is no longer being maintained.

Since the decision was taken some packages are using Java 1.7 code, there is a list [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=423734#c19) although this may have expanded since.